# li width not fixing with parent ul tag

Tags: html, css, list, vertical-alignment, box-sizing

I've checked some web pages I've developed.  There are some css problems for `li` width.

Here is the code for the navigation menu:

```css
ul.tabs {
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  background: transparent;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #ff6600;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
ul.tabs li {
  background-color: #ff6600;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  color: #f5ede3;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 0px;
  width: 16%;
  text-align: center;
}
ul.tabs li.current {
  background: #f5ede3;
  color: #ff6600;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
  <li data-tab="tabs-1" class="current">Amenities</li>
  <li data-tab="tabs-5">Attractions</li>
  <li data-tab="tabs-2">Rates</li>
  <li data-tab="tabs-6">Calendar</li>
  <li data-tab="tabs-4">Reviews</li>
  <li data-tab="tabs-3">Inquire</li>
</ul>
```

But I get the following result:

[image]

The width of the `li` tag is 16%. And the number of `li` is 6. Why is the total width of `li` tags larger than the `ul` width?

Comment: padding, margin ... ? You have 6 elements with 30px padding atleast, 180px must be more than 4% left )

Comment: You may have to set your box-sizing https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: I've set the box-sizing, but that doesn't work well.

Comment: box-sizing works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `box-sizing: border-box` globally as a *quick fix* - see demo below:

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul.tabs {
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  background: transparent;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #ff6600;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
ul.tabs li {
  background-color: #ff6600;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  color: #f5ede3;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 0px;
  width: 16%;
  text-align: center;
}
ul.tabs li.current {
  background: #f5ede3;
  color: #ff6600;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
  <li data-tab="tabs-1" class="current">Amenities</li>
  <li data-tab="tabs-5">Attractions</li>
  <li data-tab="tabs-2">Rates</li>
  <li data-tab="tabs-6">Calendar</li>
  <li data-tab="tabs-4">Reviews</li>
  <li data-tab="tabs-3">Inquire</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

With this should work:

```
ul.tabs li{
        background-color: #ff6600;
        border-top-left-radius:5px;
        border-top-right-radius:5px;
        border:none;
        color: #f5ede3;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 5px 15px;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-left:0px;
        width:16%;
        text-align:center;
        box-sizing: border-box;// Try adding this line (:
    }
```